# heroku git:clone creates empty repository

Tags: git, heroku

I'm having problems retrieving the current application code from heroku. I think it is messed up at Heroku but their support hasn't replied yet (3 days and counting). 
But maybe someone else has an idea what might be wrong or if there is something else I could try.

terminal output:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a APPNAME
Cloning from app 'APPNAME'...
Cloning into 'APPNAME'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.


$ git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

.git/config looks fine but the local directory has no branches or other content.

---

**Update**
The issue was indeed a corrupt git repository. Heroku support re-initialized the repository which fixed all problems.

Answer (score 20):

Extracted from
https://help.heroku.com/XOBUHLKQ/why-do-i-see-a-message-you-appear-to-have-cloned-an-empty-repository-when-using-heroku-git-clone

> **Why** This error message occurs when deploys to your application have been made via our platform API - typically these are deploys from
>   a Heroku Button click.
>
> - Deploy the app with Heroku Button and remember the app name that you created.
> - Go back to where the Heroku Button was displayed and copy it's underlying URL eg
>     https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/jamesward/heroku-connect-phone-change
> - Now extract the https://github.com part so from the above example you'd be left with
>     https://github.com/jamesward/heroku-connect-phone-change
> - Clone the repo with `heroku git:clone -a <YOUR-APP-NAME>` - it will be reported as empty - that's ok cd into the project and add a git
>     remote pointing at the original source,
>
>   `git remote add origin
>     https://github.com/jamesward/heroku-connect-phone-change`
> - pull from the remote origin
>
>   `git pull origin master`
> - You will now have the code for the deployed application and you can make changes to it locally and deploy it back to Heroku.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but can you explain how exactly to "copy its underlying URL"? Right clicking any heroku deploy button just gives "https://heroku.com/deploy". I am not sure how it is supposed to give you the your-app-specific `https://github.com/etc...`

Comment: That should be just the one of the repo you deployed with that convenient button anyway @AlekPiasecki

Comment: The answer still "fresh" just follow the advice and it worked out! 
https://help.heroku.com/XOBUHLKQ/why-do-i-see-a-message-you-appear-to-have-cloned-an-empty-repository-when-using-heroku-git-clone

Answer (score 5):

You can use heroku slog download. Please refer https://help.heroku.com/FZDDCBLB/how-can-i-download-my-code-from-heroku.

First, install the heroku-slugs CLI plugin with

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-slugs
```

, then run:

```
heroku slugs:download -a APP_NAME
```

This will download and compress your slug into a directory with the `app` name.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you simply cloned an empty repository.

You can try on your own. Create an empty repository (`git init a`), clone that empty repository (`git clone a b`) and try to pull from it (`cd b; git pull`).

That should give exactly the same result as in your case.

Are you sure you ever pushed any code to that application? Is it really the application you had in mind?

You can also try to create another new application, push a commit, and check whether you are able to clone it into a new directory. Maybe that will give you an idea what might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is a productive instance. It is running a nodejs app right now and I can see requests in the log files. I just don't want to push any changes before I can at least pull successfully. (probably push isn't working either)