# heroku fork + heroku git:clone = New app works but empty repository

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have a Heroku Rails app called `app1` which has source code, and works.
I wanted to create a new app inspired from it but different, with different code and URL so I ran:

```
$ heroku fork --from app1 --to app2
$ [...]
$ Fork complete. View it at https://app1.herokuapp.com/
```

I checked at that URL: The cloned app works correctly.
Now let's clone it to my local computer so that I can modify it:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a app2
Cloning into 'app2'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd app2/
$ ls
```

**PROBLEM:** Nothing in this folder. The repository is empty!
How is this even possible? Is the app working without code?
Do I have the wrong command for creating a local copy of the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804885/heroku-gitclone-creates-empty-repository/41379481#41379481

Comment: @JaimeAgudo: Do you mean that that question is a duplicate of my question?

Comment: Possibly but my point was to share the solution which is probably the same as is the only related one I found on the official heroku help @Nicolas_Raoul

Answer (score 5):

Yes, see [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app#git-repository) that states that the Git repo will be empty.

The app is working because it has the same [slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works).

In general, I advise not to think of Heroku as a source code repo - but rather put that in another place (like GitHub, say).

Answer (score 5):

Jon's answer explains why the repository is empty.
Here is how to fix the "problem":

```
$ cat app1/.git/config
```

Take note of the value of `url` in the paragraph `origin`.
It will probably look like `git@heroku.com:app1.git`.
Then run:

```
$ cd app2
$ git pull git@heroku.com:app1.git
$ git push
```

This will retrieve the source code (ignore the `Your branch is based on 'heroku/master', but the upstream is gone.` message) and replace the cloned slug with one built from this very source code.

Comment: This should be the accepted **answer** following SO guidelines